# Strip URL param using coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have query whose data contains a url like below, How can I extract the Id value from the url using coldfusion.

```
http://127.0.0.1/entity/abc.cfm?title=first-page-review&id=476

<cfif findNoCase('/entity/', qry.URL)>
    <cfset Param2 = ListGetAt(qry.URL,2,"&")>
     <cfoutput>#param2#</cfoutput>
```

This is giving the output like -> 'id=476', but I need only the numeric ID as the output. I can strip the first 3 chars to get the id, but is there a better way to do it. thanks

Comment: if the id is always after the last =, why not change your list delimiter to a = instead of a &?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your URL variables will always be consistent:

```
<cfset IDvar1 = "http://127.0.0.1/entity/abc.cfm?title=first-page-review&id=476">

<cfset IDvar2 = ListLast(IDvar1,"=") />
```

Outputting `IDvar2` yields 476.

Comment: True, but relying on position makes the code brittle. Though it is a little more work, parsing all of the parameters into a structure (like in the link above), so they can be accessed by name, offers a lot more flexibility.

Comment: @Leigh I agree completely but in the corporate world perfectionism is scarcely rewarded. Most people using CF are likely working for mid-sized businesses or government entities. I usually just assume backwards practices abound and answer the question asked.

Comment: Yes, I hear you. However, when the asker's background and restrictions are unknown, I tend to assume they raised the question because they may be unaware of the pitfalls or other options. In this specific case, it is less about perfection than avoiding something that may easily break. It is very likely the params will not always be in the same order, making it easy to unintentionally introduce a logic bug that will quickly cause problems. Since a working example is already written, may as well use it and save yourself some headaches :)